# My three demo script is too slow switching tabs

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, functional-style

My three demo stripped down script runs fine but takes 6 sec to switch from demo 2 or 3 to demo 1. Actually I need nKs = 7 which takes 30 sec. I can't find examples of slow switching tabs.

```
Manipulate[ListAnimate[G[g], 100, AnimationRepetitions -> 1] ,
   {{g, 1, ""}, {1 -> " Demo1 ", 2 -> " Demo 2 ", 3 -> " Demo 3 "}, 
  Appearance -> "DialogBox"},
 BaseStyle -> Bold, Paneled -> False, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True,
 
 Initialization :> {
   ClearAll["Global`*"]
     $Line = 1;
   tt = 24;
   silver = RGBColor[0.753, 0.753, 0.753];
   rate[a_, b_, t_] := {b[[1]] - a[[1]], b[[2]] - a[[2]]}/t;
   color[i_] := {Hue[.85], Hue[.1]}[[i]];(* purple orange *)
   eigen[i_] := {-1, 1}[[i]];  
   sq[n_] := {EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], Opacity[1], 
     color[eIndex[[n]]], 
     Rectangle[{xst, yst + 2*(n - 1)}, {xst + 2, yst + 2 + 2*(n - 1)}],
     Text[
      Style[eigen[eIndex[[n]]], FontSize -> 15, Opacity[1], 
       Black] , {xst + 1, yst + 1 + 2*(n - 1)}],
     EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], Opacity[1], 
     color[-eIndex[[n]]], 
     Rectangle[{xst + 2, yst + 2*(n - 1)}, {xst + 4, 
       yst + 2 + 2*(n - 1)}],
     Text[
      Style[eigen[-eIndex[[n]]], FontSize -> 15, Opacity[1], 
       Black] , {xst + 3, yst + 1 + 2*(n - 1)}
      ]};
   temp5 = Graphics[Table[sq[i], {i, 10}]]; (*  
   waterfall   complete   *)
   
   text1 = 
    "                                              Demo 1. Text \
starts here
    10. Demo  2 shows how etc.
    ";
   
   G[1] := frames1;
   idle = .6;
   nKs = 2; (* Max 7 *)
   gs = {33, 14};
   d1 = {33, 24};
   bk1 = {36.9, 14};
   p1 = bk1;
   xst = 37;
   yst = 8;
   eIndex = {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2}; (*   
   Pseudo random string   *)
   d1time0 = 
    tt*EuclideanDistance[gs, 
       d1]/(EuclideanDistance[gs, d1] + EuclideanDistance[d1, p1]);
    avgRate = Norm[rate[gs, d1, d1time0]];
   bk1time = EuclideanDistance[bk1, bk1 - 2]/avgRate;
   frames1 = {};
   For[k = 1, k < nKs + 1, k++,
    frame0 = Table[Graphics[{
        {Nest[Lighter, Blue, 6], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {30, 25}], Black, 
         Inset[
          Pane[TextCell[text1, "Text", FontSize -> 16], 550], {1, 
           25}, {Left, Top}]},
        If[k > 1,
         Inset[
          temp5, {10.68, 
           17 + t*rate[{0, 0}, {-1.8, 0}, tt][[1]] - 2*(k - 2)}, {12, 
           12}, Scaled[{.815, .815}]]],
        {Opacity[1], White, Rectangle[{34, 15}, {40, 26}]},   (*  
        shade   *)
        } ,
       ImageSize -> {800, 480},
       PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 25}}],
       {t, 0, tt + bk1time + idle, 0.1}];
    frames1 = Flatten[Append[frames1, frame0]];] ,
   
   G[2] := frames3;
   frames3 = {};
   For[k = 1, k < 7, k++,
    frame0 = Table[Graphics[{Black, Disk[{t/2, t/2}, 1.1]
        }, ImageSize -> {800, 480},
       PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 25}}],
       {t, 0, 24, 0.1}];
    frames3 = Flatten[Append[frames3, frame0]];] ,
   
   G[3] := frames4;
   frames4 = {};
   For[k = 1, k < 7, k++,
    frame0 = Table[Graphics[{Black, Circle[{t/2, t/2}, 1.1]
        }, ImageSize -> {800, 480},
       PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 25}}],
       {t, 0, 24, 0.1}];
    frames4 = Flatten[Append[frames4, frame0]];] 
           }
 ]
```

> A different version where only Demo 1 works is very fast to load but
> I can't figure out how to correctly implement the G[*] function calls
> of the slow version along with the frames[[i]] format  of the fast
> version. Nor can I get the tabs and sliders to work on the fast
> version.

```
Manipulate[frames1[[i]], {{i, 1, "frame"}, 1, Length@frames1, 1}
 , {{g, 1, ""}, {1 -> " Demo 1 ", 2 -> " Demo 2 ", 3 -> " Demo 3 "}, 
  Appearance -> "DialogBox"}
 , BaseStyle -> Bold, Paneled -> False, ControlPlacement -> Top, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 
 , Initialization :> {...........
```

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After guessing a bunch, I replaces the For and Append loop with Flatten[Reap[Do[Sow[Table[Graphics...  in two Modules. Now, regardless of Module complexity, with two indices Manipulate switches very fast.

```
Manipulate[
 frames0[[g, i]], {{i, 1, ""}, 1, nFrames, 1, Appearance -> {"Open"}}
 , {{g, 1, ""}, {1 -> " Demo1 ", 2 -> " Demo 2 "}
  , Appearance -> {"DialogBox"}
  }
 , Initialization :> {
   ClearAll["Global`*"];
   tt = 24;
   fPeriod = .1;
   timeTot = 27.9;
   nKs = 7; 
   nFrames = Round[timeTot/fPeriod]*nKs;
   frames0 = {frames1, frames2};
   
   Module[{i, t},
    frames1 = Flatten[Reap[Do[Sow[Table[Graphics[{Disk[{1.5 t, t}]}
             , ImageSize -> {800, 480}
             , PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 25}}]
            , {t, 0, timeTot, fPeriod}]]
          , {i, 1, 7}]][[2]]];],
   
   Module[{i, t},
    frames2 = Flatten[Reap[Do[Sow[Table[Graphics[{Circle[{1.5 t, t}]}
            , ImageSize -> {800, 480}
            , PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {0, 25}}]
            , {t, 0, timeTot, fPeriod}]]
         , {i, 1, 7}]][[2]]]]
   }
 ]
```